# Is Firebase supposed to run on the client?

Tags: javascript, web, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

I'm interested in using Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/), I've looked at their docs and their JavaScript examples seem to run on the client, am I being really stupid or is that a bad idea?

Like the database feature for example:

```
function writeUserData(userId, name, email) {
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email
  });
}
```

Whats to stop someone opening up the console in the browser and putting anything they want in the database, maybe thousands of times?

Also, I spun up a node/express server and managed to get the database functionality working fine on the server, but unfortunately I couldn't for their authentication feature, maybe because it needs to send the token to the client?

Comment: i don't think anything is stopping anyone, but why would someone write thousands of values to the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write [security rules for your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/), that validate the data that is saved and ensure that users can only read/write data that they're authorized for.

For example, you could ensure that users can only modify their own node under `/users` with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I highly recommend reading the [documentation on the security rules for the Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Comment: Thanks for this, Firebase makes much more sense now. One more question if you don't mind, when using Firebase email and password authentication, does Firebase provide any validation for user input when registering for an account or is that something I should take care of server side?

Comment: You can do it on server side using Regex.But it is a better practice to implement it on client side as well.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, your application code is all meant to be run on the client